# Mac OS style TabView

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

I have just started to code for Mac OS X and I'm very excited about tab controls, just like this one:

[image]

But I can not understand how to implement it. Is there a standard UIKit control or some external control, or maybe this is just a set of buttons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/_index.html) is [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS) specific and is not used on OS X. You are looking for [`NSToolbar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Great! Thanks, how can I miss it (

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard `NSToolbar` control. You can find it in palette of standard controls in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks, answer was so simple, sorry to distract you )